# Sprintf in when using matrixes

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to run the `sprintf` function in the code below, but it gives `segfault`, no idea why.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // works fine
    char a[80] = "";
    char * b = "INTER";
    char * c = "10";
    sprintf(a, "%s %s", b, c);

    // for matrix
    int nvparam;
    char **vparam_values, 
         **vparam_keys, 
         **vparam;

    //params
    nvparam   = 1;
    vparam = ( char ** ) malloc( nvparam * sizeof( char [80] ) );
    vparam_keys = ( char ** ) malloc( nvparam * sizeof( char * ) );
    vparam_values = ( char ** ) malloc( nvparam * sizeof( char * ) );

    vparam[0] = "";
    vparam_keys[0] = "ITER";
    vparam_values[0] = "10";

    // test
    printf("%s\n", vparam_keys[0]);
    printf("%s\n", vparam_values[0]);
    // FAILING ZONE BEGINS
    sprintf(vparam[0], "%s %s", vparam_keys[0], vparam_values[0]); // for matrix it fails
    // FAILING ZONE ENDS
    printf("%s\n", vparam[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

The `segfault` manifests in the line `sprintf(vparam[0], "%s %s", vparam_keys[0], vparam_values[0]);`. It works just fine for regular arrays, but for matrices it fails.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: What language are you really using?  Is it C or is it C++?

Comment: Can you point your finger to the actual line in the shown code that allocates sufficient memory for `vparam[0]`? This is a trick question, there's no such line in the shown code. Hence the crash.

Comment: Tried compiling both ways, and both failed.

Comment: Despite many assertions to the contrary, C and C++ are not the same language. In C++ you have `std::string` and `std::vector` and a lot of this code goes straight in the trash since there's better ways of doing it. In C you're not so lucky.

Comment: `sprintf` into a string constant is a good way to crash. `vparam[0]` is not writable. `char a[80]` is writable, but `""` is not.

Comment: ...not only that, but `vparam[0] = "";` doesn't even allocate enough bytes, so even if it is writable, something else will be damaged.

Comment: `vparam = ( char ** ) malloc( nvparam * sizeof( char [80] ) );` This is totally wrong. If you want a pointer to an array of 80 characters, `char**` isn't it.

Comment: As an aside, if you are allocating an array of pointers (which is what you do when you assign  to vparam), you should use the size of a pointer.

Comment: @MatheusDiógenesAndrade Is your goal to build 3 `nvParam x 80` character matrices?  If it is, your attempt is very far off.  This doesn't have anything to do with `sprintf`.

Comment: @MatheusDiógenesAndrade -- *Tried compiling both ways, and both failed* -- You need to choose a language and stick with it.  Even though the tags were changed to `C`, is the actual language you are using C++?  This is highly important, because if it is C++ and you are given a `C` answer, that may not be a good answer given the actual language you are using.   For example, a `C` answer would not need to cast the return value of `malloc`, while C++ it is required.

Comment: Thank you very much @tadman, it is exactly this the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters this memory allocation

```
vparam = ( char ** ) malloc( nvparam * sizeof( char [80] ) );
```

does not make sense. If you want to allocate a two-dimensional array then you should write for example

```
char ( *vparam )[80] = malloc( nvparam * sizeof( char [80] ) );
```

Or if the compiler supports variable length arrays then

```
char ( *vparam )[80] = malloc( sizeof( char [nvparam][80] ) );
```

After this statement

```
vparam[0] = "";
```

the pointer `vparam[0]` (`vparam` is declared in your code with the type `char **`) points to a string literal. And this call

```
sprintf(vparam[0], "%s %s", vparam_keys[0], vparam_values[0]);
```

tries to change the string literal pointed to by the pointer that results in undefined behavior.

You could write

```
char ( *vparam )[80] = malloc( nvparam * sizeof( char [80] ) );
char **vparam_keys = malloc( nvparam * sizeof( char * ) );
char **vparam_values = malloc( nvparam * sizeof( char * ) );

vparam_keys[0] = "ITER";
vparam_values[0] = "10";

sprintf(vparam[0], "%s %s", vparam_keys[0], vparam_values[0]);
```

In this case the expression `vparam[0]` has the character array type `char[80]`. So the result of calling `sprintf` will be the same as in your first code snippet.